# Add icons to list with ::before

Tags: html, css

I'm working with Bootstrap. I'm trying to add an image as number icon to my list. It is kind of a bad practice to add `<div>` tag inside `<ul>` tag, so is it possible to add icon with `::before`?

Here's my code:

```html
<ul class="lizt" id="sub-lizt">
  <li class="item"><a href="#Item_name">1. Bunch of geebrish</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#Item_name">2. Bunch of geebrish</a></li >
</ul>
```

Comment: You can do it with span tag.

Comment: You can add everything on a li if you want. You can add an icon with a font or as an image here. Just css can solve this

Comment: I saw many websites source.They have nothing but ::before element there.

Comment: you will never find before in the source code ... it's only visible on CSS and when inspecting live website

Answer (score 0):

```
ul {
 list-style-image: url('/your_img_path.jpg');
}
```

You can use this in your CSS. For in-depth just take a look [Here.](https://techforluddites.com/replacing-list-bullets-with-images-using-css/)

Answer (score 0):

Putting a `div` inside an `li` tag is not a bad practice. It would be wrong to put a `div` directly inside a list `ol`/`ul`, but not inside a list item.

That being said, you don't need a `div` to put a numbered image as bullet for your list, because, in fact, [`list-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style) property allows using an image as bullet.

```css
.item {
  list-style: url('http://via.placeholder.com/32x32/000/fff?text=1');
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  list-style: url('http://via.placeholder.com/32x32/000/fff?text=2');
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  list-style: url('http://via.placeholder.com/32x32/000/fff?text=3');
}
```

```html
<ol class="lizt" id="sub-lizt">
  <li class="item"><a href="#Item_name">Bunch of geebrish</a></li>
  <li class="item"><a href="#Item_name">Bunch of geebrish</a></li >
  <li class="item"><a href="#Item_name">Bunch of geebrish</a></li >
</ol>
```

You'd probably want your images vertically aligned in the middle with your text. In that case, you have many options, like moving up your `a` elements from its relative position.

```
.item a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.75em;
}
```